# When does SharedPreferences are being read from disk?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm not actually sure the cycle of getting SharedPreferences of Android app.

Are they being read during getPreferences()(and stored in memory)?
Or they are being read during SharedPreferences#getBoolean()?(getInt(), etc)

Comment: Here is a tested code. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14912030/2069130 . You can get more help about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says " Retrieve and hold the contents..." when using [getSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), so they are stored in memory when you call it.