# SharedPreferences don't seem to be updated when coming back to the HomeScreen Activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, auto-update

I have two activities. One is **HomeScreen** and the other one is **GridView**. The app opens with the HomeScreen Activity which has the *SharedPreferences* as below.

After I select the play button and move on to the next Activity which is **GridView** and play a game it should add the scores to the *SharedPreferences* but when I press the back button to go back to the **HomeScreen** Activity, the scores don't seem to be updated unless I force close and reopen. Calling the **onResume()** method will double the score instead of once.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    addScores();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_game);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showMovieDialog();
        }
    });
}

public void addScores(){
    final SharedPreferences app_preferences =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    totalCoins = app_preferences.getInt("Scores: ",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
    totalCoins = totalCoins + Bollywood.coins;

    tCoins = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalCoins);
    tCoins.setText("" + totalCoins);

    editor.putInt("Scores: ", totalCoins);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Consider it, u might get help http://stackoverflow.com/q/14912030/2069130

Answer (score -1):

This code is looking for trouble if I read it right. Every time **onResume()** is called, the scores will be added up from **Bollywood.coins**. Your users are going to very quickly discover that they can rack up high scores just by tilting their device back and forth, causing your app to repeatedly restart.

You also don't say where **Bollywood.coins** is defined or set.

I think you're also making some dangerous assumptions about activity lifecycles.

Instead, I would have your **GridView** activity update the scores in the shared preferences when the user finishes a game, and then let the main activity read those scores back.

At this point, I think we need to see some code snippets from your game activity so we can see what it's doing.

(As an aside, **GridView** is a poor name for an activity, since there's a widget by that name as well -- it gets a little confusing.)